# prove or disprove: if $f$ and $g$ are monotonic increasing, then $f(n)=O(g(n))$ or $g(n)=O(f(n))$

Tags: asymptotics

I'm trying to prove (or disprove) that if $f$ and $g$ are monotonic increasing, then $f(n)=O(g(n))$ or $g(n)=O(f(n))$ but with no success. Can someone help me with this? thanks.

Comment: Hint: try to construct a counter-example with $f(n)=ng(n)$ if $n$ is even, and $g(n)=nf(n)$ if $n$ is odd.

Comment: I tried to, but I guess I didn't fully understand it

Answer (score 2):

The following is a *disproof*:

Put $f(k):=k!$ $(k\geq1)$ and
$$g(3m+j):=(3m)!\qquad(m\geq1, \ -1\leq j\leq 1)\ .$$
Then $f(3m)=g(3m)$ $(m\geq1)$ and
$${f(3m+1)\over g(3m+1)}=3m+1,\qquad {g(3m-1)\over f(3m-1)}=3m\qquad(m\geq1)\ .$$